# Laravel 5 - Custom User Authentification with LDAP

Tags: laravel, ldap, laravel-5

I would like to create a custom user authentification with LDAP - this is how it should work:

User enters his credentials - I'll check with LDAP is the user exists, if yes I'll create a session in a database and return a valid token for a request. The token handler is not the problem, but I'm not sure about the LDAP Authentification.

What I've already done:

```
activated php_ldap extension
```

Installed the php-ldap-module for L5 with the description from here:

http://packalyst.com/packages/package/strebl/l5-ldap-auth

So now I've got my new Authentification Provider, but when I'll try with:

```php
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => 'user', 'password' => 'password']))
{
    .....
}
```

Nothing happens - no error, no warning. Can I use now `Auth::attempt`, or is that another function for checking if a user exists in my LDAP Directory. Is it still `email` and `password` as properties for the login attempt?

Is there somebody who is working with this extension and can give me some more information about the usage?

Thanks in advance

Comment: From the [configuration info](https://github.com/strebl/ldap-auth#configuration) it seems like you should specify that the username field is `email` in your case: `'username_field' => 'email'`.

Comment: Ah fine thanks - i will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to follow these instructions:

[laravel-simple-ldap-auth](https://github.com/jotaelesalinas/laravel-simple-ldap-auth)

There it is explained how to create a custom LDAP authentication in Laravel 5.